# How to Work with Ruby Duck Typing

Tags: ruby, duck-typing

I am learning Ruby and I'm having a major conceptual problem concerning typing. Allow me to detail why I don't understand with paradigm.

Say I am method chaining for concise code as you do in Ruby. I have to precisely know what the return type of each method call in the chain, otherwise I can't know what methods are available on the next link. Do I have to check the method documentation every time?? I'm running into this constantly running tutorial exercises. It seems I'm stuck with a process of reference, infer, run, fail, fix, repeat to get code running rather then knowing precisely what I'm working with during coding. This flies in the face of Ruby's promise of intuitiveness.

Say I am using a third party library, once again I need to know what types are allow to pass on the parameters otherwise I get a failure. I can look at the code but there may or may not be any comments or declaration of what type the method is expecting. I understand you code based on methods are available on an object, not the type. But then I have to be sure whatever I pass as a parameter has all the methods the library is expect, so I still have to do type checking. Do I have to hope and pray everything is documented properly on an interface so I know if I'm expected to give a string, a hash, a class, etc.

If I look at the source of a method I can get a list of methods being called and infer the type expected, but I have to perform analysis.

[Ruby and duck typing: design by contract impossible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177080/ruby-and-duck-typing-design-by-contract-impossible)

The discussions in the preceding stackoverflow question don't really answer anything other than "there are processes you have to follow" and those processes don't seem to be standard, everyone has a different opinion on what process to follow, and the language has zero enforcement. Method Validation? Test-Driven Design? Documented API? Strict Method Naming Conventions? What's the standard and who dictates it? What do I follow? Would these guidelines solve this concern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616037/ruby-coding-style-guidelines? Is there editors that help?

Conceptually I don't get the advantage either. You need to know what methods are needed for any method called, so regardless you are typing when you code anything. You just aren't informing the language or anyone else explicitly, unless you decide to document it. Then you are stuck doing all type checking at runtime instead of during coding. I've done PHP and Python programming and I don't understand it there either.

What am I missing or not understanding? Please help me understand this paradigm.

Comment: There are certainly advantages to duck typing, but there are of course disadvantages as well.  I can pass *any* object to a method `foo(a)` that calls `a.bar` as long as `a.responds_to?(:bar)`.  That's nice.  No interfaces, no generics, just add a method `bar` and go.  Of course, static typing has many advantages as well.  Sounds like you just need some experience with the Ruby way to appreciate both.  Also sounds like you may have been a bit spoiled by intellisense (or similar features).  Many (*many*) of us have to check documentation early and often.

Comment: Intuition is the result of training so nothing is intuitive until you've trained yourself to use it.

Comment: This question suffers from "TL;DR". It'd help for you to summarize it and throw away the rest otherwise it's too broad. "This flies in the face of Ruby's promise of intuitiveness." Intuitiveness to who? Matz says it's designed to be intuitive to him, and that he believes it will become intuitive to others who have used it sufficiently. It's impossible to create a language that is immediately intuitive to everyone, so his goal is spot-on.

Comment: Possibly "[How is duck typing different from the old 'variant' type and/or interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289176/how-is-duck-typing-different-from-the-old-variant-type-and-or-interfaces)" would be a good read for you.

Comment: I find it ironic that you say "spoiled by intellisense" when talking about a language where its stated purpose is to reduce coding complexity. I program both ways on a daily basis regardless.

Comment: I'm reading that link you posted and now I have MORE duck typing questions -_-

Comment: I found your remarks very interesting, but have a request: after you've used Ruby awhile, do an edit to tell us if your views have changed, and if so, how and why.

Comment: @kamegami: When you complain about being forced to read documentation I can only assume that you have been "spoiled" by features like intellisense.  "Intuitive" doesn't mean "everything is magically as you hope it to be".  Complaining about reading documentation is a bit like a middle class American complaining about driving an older model car instead of a 2013 Mustang.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Ruby specific problem, it's the same for all dynamically typed languages.

Usually there are no guidelines for how to document this either (and most of the time not really possible). See for instance [map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) in the ruby documentation

```
map { |item| block } → new_ary
map → Enumerator
```

What is `item`, `block` and `new_ary` here and how are they related? There's no way to tell unless you know the implementation or can infer it from the name of the function somehow. Specifying the type is also hard since `new_ary` depends on what `block` returns, which in turn depends on the type of `item`, which could be different for each element in the Array.

A lot of times you also stumble across documentation that says that an argument is of type `Object`, Which again tells you nothing since everything is an Object.

OCaml has a solution for this, it supports structural typing so a function that needs an object with a property `foo` that's a `String` will be inferred to be `{ foo : String }` instead of a concrete type. But OCaml is still statically typed.

Worth noting is that this can be a problem in statically typed lanugages too. Scala has very generic methods on collections which leads to type signatures like `++[B >: A, That](that: GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Array[T], B, That]): That` for appending two collections.

So most of the time, you will just have to learn this by heart in dynamically typed languages, and perhaps help improve the documentation of libraries you are using.

And this is why I prefer static typing ;)

**Edit** One thing that might make sense is to do what Scala also does. It doesn't actually show you that type signature for `++` by default, instead it shows `++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): Array[B]` which is not as generic, but probably covers most of the use cases. So for Ruby's map it could have a monomorphic type signature like `Array<a> -> (a -> b) -> Array<b>`. It's only correct for the cases where the list only contains values of one type and the block only returns elements of one other type, but it's much easier to understand and gives a good overview of what the function does.

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head, this is my exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you seem to misunderstand the concept. It's not a replacement for static type checking. It's just *different*. For example, if you convert objects to json (for rendering them to client), you don't care about actual type of the object, as long as it has `#to_json` method. In Java, you'd have to create `IJsonable` interface. In ruby no overhead is needed.

As for knowing what to pass where and what returns what: memorize this or consult docs each time. We all do that.

Just another day, I've seen rails programmer with 6+ years of experience complain on twitter that he can't memorize order of parameters to `alias_method`: does new name go first or last?

> This flies in the face of Ruby's promise of intuitiveness.

Not really. Maybe it's just badly written library. In core ruby everything is quite intuitive, I dare say.

Statically typed languages with their powerful IDEs have a small advantage here, because they can show you documentation right here, very quickly. This is still accessing documentation, though. Only quicker.

Comment: I think you're close to what I'm getting at. As you say you would declare IJsonable. In Ruby you don't declare that. Then HOW do you know you need that interface?? As you say, you MUST consult the documentation, and the documentation MUST declare you need that interface, otherwise there is no way of knowing without checking the code. Then what's the advantage, you have to declare in documents, why not declare it in code, then your IDE knows the interface and can actual automate things for you. What's even the overhead of declaring your interface.

Comment: The overhead of interface is another entity in the system. What is this strange library you're having troubles with? Most of what I worked with, they accept either primitives (strings, arrays, hashes, etc) (which is obvious from the documentation) or objects from the same library (which are, again, documented).

Comment: If you give a wrong object to a method, it will raise error. That will be detected by tests.

Comment: The advantage here is the ability to write one-two lines of code, uncluttered by type information, which accomplish the same (or more) as 100 lines of java code.

Comment: I'm mostly speaking in hypotheticals as I haven't dug super deep into the library. Sounds like the answer is to design everything to accept primitives and hint the iterface with the method naming convention (again this implies process standards that are not part of the language). I've done enough open source coding to know to not expect proper comments and documentation. Heck, static type languages at least let you generate documentation, crummy as they usually are. Is there documentation standards for Ruby? A jDoc-like comment standard?

Comment: Yeah, but type declaration doesn't take 100 lines of code. I don't see how duck typing simplifies anything.

Comment: RDoc/YARD are widely used for documentation generation

Answer (score 2):

Consider that the design choices of strongly typed languages (C++,Java,C#,et al) enforce strict declarations of type passed to methods, and type returned by methods.  This is because these languages were designed to validate that arguments are correct (and since these languages are compiled, this work can be done at compile time).  But some questions can only be answered at run time, and C++ for example has the RTTI (Run Time Type Interpreter) to examine and enforce type guarantees.  But as the developer, you are guided by syntax, semantics and the compiler to produce code that follows these type constraints.

Ruby gives you flexibility to take dynamic argument types, and return dynamic types.  This freedom enables you to write more generic code (read Stepanov on the STL and generic programming), and gives you a rich set of introspection methods (is_a?, instance_of?, respond_to?, kind_of?, is_array?, et al) which you can use dynamically.  Ruby enables you to write generic methods, but you can also explicity enforce design by contract, and process failure of contract by means chosen.

Yes, you will need to use care when chaining methods together, but learning Ruby is not just a few new keywords.  Ruby supports multiple paradigms; you can write procedural, object oriend, generic, and functional programs.  The cycle you are in right now will improve quickly as you learn about Ruby.

Perhaps your concern stems from a bias towards strongly typed languages (C++, Java, C#, et al).  Duck typing is a different approach.  You think differently.  Duck typing means that if an object looks like a , behaves like a , then it is a .  Everything (almost) is an Object in Ruby, so everything is polymorphic.

Consider templates (C++ has them, C# has them, Java is getting them, C has macros).  You build an algorithm, and then have the compiler generate instances for your chosen types.  You aren't doing design by contract with generics, but when you recognize their power, you write less code, and produce more.

Some of your other concerns,

- third party libraries (gems) are not as hard to use as you fear
- Documented API?  See Rdoc and http://www.ruby-doc.org/
- Rdoc documentation is (usually) provided for libraries
- coding guidelines - look at the source for a couple of simple gems for starters
- naming conventions - snake case and camel case are both popular

Suggestion - approach an online tutorial with an open mind, do the tutorial (http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/ is good), and you will have more focused questions.

Comment: This seems to be the answer I was looking. So I should be performing introspection as proper runtime checks on parameters. And then you MUST generate documentation in place of type or interface declarations. Can documentation be generated from introspection checks? I would feel a lot more comfortable about saying you must follow convention if there was a PEP8 equivalent to point and say "this is done wrong".

Comment: @kamegami: Ruby's introspection will not discover intended types from code, so it cannot generate full documentation without help. However, doc tools such as `yard` do allow coders to declare types for params and return values. Therefore you rely on the library developers' good intentions with documentation. It's possible to write very thorough and accurate documentation, if you have time and inclination.

Comment: Seems as though if there was a standard convention for declaring parameter intent (what I'm gonna call an object having the interface you expect) you could handle interface documentation, error handling, and IDE static intent analysis (Intellisense style) in one foul swoop. I CAN'T be the only person to think of this for a dynamic type language.

Comment: My degree was in Mathematics so I studied proofs and then formal methods for specification, design, and construction of correct programs.  I understand and appreciate  the rigorous approach of strongly typed languages.  Languages I know do not offer intrinsic constructs for formal declarations of weakest preconditions, nor formal specification of behavior.  C and C++ check types but allow coercion and pointer arithmetic, C++ does const-correctness.  Java avoids pointer arithmetic and coercion.  But all have generics.  Ruby, Perl, Javascript, Lua, Python all have relaxed typing.

Comment: And I have found that these weakly typed langauages, Ruby/Perl/Javascript/Lua, are more productive (build more working features quicker).  With the caveat that careful programming is needed.